# Fan noise in LG U460 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, fan, temperature, noise, lg

Today after two days using Ubuntu 16.04 without problems, my laptop started to do a fan noise that's bothering me a lot, the fan is always on, and running as if on peaks , pulsating.

I'm trying to make fancontrol in ubuntu following this tutorial
https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/

but when I use `pwmconfig`it return

```
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I already tried

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

but without sucess.

Comment: are you sure you don't have something busy in the background ?

Comment: What is your video card?