# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Fan works at max speed on HP Envy 6-1154er

Tags: 16.04, power-management, hp, fan

I tried many different things. I spent days by googling and trying different steps in intention to resolve this issue. But with no success.

I already asked about the issue in this question: [Abnormal fan behavior: Sticking and persist on max speed (HP Envy 6-1154er & Ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706737/abnormal-fan-behavior-sticking-and-persist-on-max-speed-hp-envy-6-1154er-ubu). It enumerates several steps I tried.

I tried install TLP. Now I installed LMT (Laptop Mode Tools): [Laptop can't control fan speed after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762057/laptop-cant-control-fan-speed-after-16-04-upgrade). I installed Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade. I previously had 14.04 (And the issue exists since it's installation). I installed 4.6 kernel. So, due to I have new OS I decided to ask the same again as It seems my previous topic won't be answered.

Possible solution:
I noticed when the fan works on max speed and temperature is in range 59-69C (The CPU is "cold") If I unplug the AC power supply from the laptop, the fan's speed gets low as it should after a couple of seconds or sometimes about tens of seconds.

So, I think if I were able somehow tell the LMT or the OS that the laptop is on the battery always regardless of it's actual connection to power supply, I probably would be able to get what I want: gently working fan. This is only thing left that I can't still beat. I don't want to get windows back.

```
q@4xybook:~$ sudo laptop_mode status
```

Gives this when AC is plugged.

```
Mounts:
   /dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sdb1 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
   /dev/sda2 on /home/q/media type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/stuff-loc type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/work type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/apps type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)

Drive power status:

   /dev/sda:
    drive state is:  active/idle

   /dev/sdb:
    drive state is:  active/idle

(NOTE: drive settings affected by Laptop Mode cannot be retrieved.)

Readahead states:
   /dev/sda2: 3072 kB
   /dev/sdb1: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda1: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda2: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB

Laptop Mode Tools is allowed to run: /var/run/laptop-mode-tools/enabled exists.

/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode:
   2

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio:
   60

/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs:
   3000

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio:
   1

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs:
   36000

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs:
   36000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   1596539

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   1603843

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2399988

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2399988

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state:
   state:      open

/sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/online:
   1

Mounts:
   /dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sdb1 on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
   /dev/sda2 on /home/q/media type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/stuff-loc type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/work type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)
   /dev/sda3 on /home/q/apps type ext4 (rw,relatime,commit=360,data=ordered)

Drive power status:

   /dev/sda:
    drive state is:  active/idle

   /dev/sdb:
    drive state is:  active/idle

(NOTE: drive settings affected by Laptop Mode cannot be retrieved.)

Readahead states:
   /dev/sda2: 3072 kB
   /dev/sdb1: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda1: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda2: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB
   /dev/sda3: 3072 kB

Laptop Mode Tools is allowed to run: /var/run/laptop-mode-tools/enabled exists.

/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode:
   2

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio:
   60

/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs:
   3000

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio:
   1

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs:
   36000

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs:
   36000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2399988

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2399988

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2414796

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:
   2414066

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:
   2600000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:
   800000

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor:
   powersave

/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state:
   state:      open

/sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/online:
   1

Laptop mode 
enabled, active [unchanged]
```

And this if it's unplugged

```
q@4xybook:~$ sudo laptop_mode status

...
/sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/online:
   0

Laptop mode 
enabled, active [unchanged]
```

Any ideas?

**-- UPDATE --**

Can a kind soul tell me: Is it possible to make the laptop always work in battery mode regardless of it's actual state?

Comment: Try using `cpufreq-tools`.

Comment: I tried this https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/indicator-cpufreq. It made no difference.

Comment: not just the indicator, the tools as well

Comment: Does fancontrol work (I don't expect it to; you have a consumer laptop)? If it does, great, you can control the fan. Run a script that executes and adjusts fan levels when AC is unplugged. However, I believe this is an HP BIOS issue. Many consumer HP laptops, mine included, will run the fan at high speed when plugged in. Was this an issue under Windows?

Comment: It doesn't. The service is not even run, due to pwmconfig fails to generate /etc/fancontrol with: /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.  May be it's possible to write this file by my own? Or I can try to upgrade the BIOS. There is no such an issue under Windows.

Comment: Is it solution to buy new laptop from the Ubuntu compatibility list? Would OS little details work better? I mean e.g. touchpad that always dies and I must reset it by: modprobe -r ps-mouse ... Wi-Fi issues...

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually things become ok after I did the things suggested by @Ingo. I removed [intel_powerclamp](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIyOTE). The road to hell is definetly based on good intentions...

```
sudo rmmod intel_powerclamp
```

To disable it permanently and suppress loading it altogether, in addition do:

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo su
echo install intel_powerclamp /bin/true  >intel_powerclamp.conf
```

[intel_powerclamp: Start/Stop forced idle injection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457252/intel-powerclamp-start-stop-forced-idle-injection)